AWS Neptune Significant Latency in AWS Gremlin Queries in Large Graph Database
I am facing slow query performance and timeouts. The graph contains over 25 million nodes and 29 million edges, and performance issues arise during complex graph-wide operations.
Environment Details
Neptune serverless cluster in ap-southeast-1 with the following
specifications:

ARN: arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:120*****
Engine Version: 1.3.2.1
NCU Range: 1-128
Data Volume: ~25 million nodes and ~29 million edges
Access Method: Jupyter Notebook with Gremlin queries

Performance Observations
Experiencing significant query latency with graph-wide operations.The queries are  taking substantially longer than expected (more than 30min), even after  implementing Neptune Analytics functions.
Moreover, the same Gremlin query which took less than 7min to run took more than  30min when run for the second time. Given below an example for such query.
%%gremlin
g.V().hasLabel('hh')
 .where(__.not(__.out('has_dtv_connection'))) // Households without DTV connection
 .as('hhNode')
 .union(
 __.out('has_mob_connection'), // Get all mobile connections
 __.out('has_hbb_connection') // Get all home broadband connections
 )
 .hasLabel('mob', 'hbb') // Ensure we're looking at mobile or HBB nodes
 .has('SPORTS_CRICKET_LOVER', gt(0)) // Cricket lovers (non-zero)
 .select('hhNode') // Back to the original household
 .by('HH_CELL_LOC_DISTRICT') // Select district
 .groupCount()
 .next()


Here is the error that occurred when running the above query.
{
"code": "TimeLimitExceededException",
"requestId": "db0064f7-6423-42e4-8b77-947cd52cf098",
"detailedMessage": "A timeout occurred within the script during evaluation.",
"message": "A timeout occurred within the script during evaluation."
}
\n Node properties are the following:\n [{'properties': [{'property': 'HH_TYPE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'HH_DISTINCT_NIC_COUNT', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'IS_NEW_HOUSEHOLD', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'HH_CELL_LOC_DISTRICT', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'HH_CLASSIFICATION', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'IS_CHURNED_HOUSEHOLD', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'HH_MONTHLY_DATA_USAGE_MB', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'HH_SITE_ID', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'HH_SIZE', 'type': 'INTEGER'}], 'labels': 'hh'}, {'properties': [{'property': 'CONTACT_GENDER', 'type': 'LIST'}, {'property': 'PREFERRED_LANGUAGE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'NATIONALITY', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'TITLE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'PREFERRED_LANGUAGE', 'type': 'LIST'}, {'property': 'AGE', 'type': 'LIST'}, {'property': 'AGE', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CONTACT_GENDER', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'TITLE', 'type': 'LIST'}], 'labels': 'cus'}, {'properties': [{'property': 'SUPER_MARKET_SHOPPER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'FACEBOOK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'COMPLAINER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CHURN_PROPENSITY', 'type': 'DOUBLE'}, {'property': 'ACCOUNT_TYPE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'ACCOUNT_STATUS', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'LINKEDIN_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'SPORTS_CRICKET_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'INTEREST_IN_CLOTHING_OUTLETS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'IS_NEW_CONNECTION', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'LOB', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'SOCIAL_MEDIA_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'ENTERTAINMENT_MOVIE_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CX_STATE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'TIKTOK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'INSTAGRAM_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'NEWS_READERS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'WHATSAPP', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'GENIE_USER_YES_NO', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'IS_PD_CONNECTION', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'NETWORK_STAY', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'BANK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DATA_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'ARPU', 'type': 'DOUBLE'}, {'property': 'CHURN_MONTHS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'TAXI_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DEVICE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'ENTERTAINMENT_MUSIC_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'TWITTER_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'EZCASH_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'YOUTUBE_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'USERS_OF_HOSPITAL_CHANNELING', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CYBER_GAMERS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DEVICE_TYPE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'VIDEO_CONFERENCING_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}], 'labels': 'mob'}, {'properties': [{'property': 'SUPER_MARKET_SHOPPER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'FACEBOOK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'COMPLAINER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CHURN_PROPENSITY', 'type': 'DOUBLE'}, {'property': 'ACCOUNT_TYPE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'ACCOUNT_STATUS', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'LINKEDIN_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'SPORTS_CRICKET_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'INTEREST_IN_CLOTHING_OUTLETS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'IS_NEW_CONNECTION', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'LOB', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'SOCIAL_MEDIA_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'ENTERTAINMENT_MOVIE_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CX_STATE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'TIKTOK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'INSTAGRAM_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'NEWS_READERS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'WHATSAPP', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'GENIE_USER_YES_NO', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'IS_PD_CONNECTION', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'NETWORK_STAY', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'BANK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DATA_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'ARPU', 'type': 'DOUBLE'}, {'property': 'CHURN_MONTHS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'TAXI_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DEVICE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'ENTERTAINMENT_MUSIC_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'TWITTER_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'EZCASH_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'YOUTUBE_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'USERS_OF_HOSPITAL_CHANNELING', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CYBER_GAMERS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DEVICE_TYPE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'VIDEO_CONFERENCING_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}], 'labels': 'dtv'}, {'properties': [{'property': 'SUPER_MARKET_SHOPPER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'FACEBOOK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'COMPLAINER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CHURN_PROPENSITY', 'type': 'DOUBLE'}, {'property': 'ACCOUNT_TYPE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'ACCOUNT_STATUS', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'LINKEDIN_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'SPORTS_CRICKET_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'INTEREST_IN_CLOTHING_OUTLETS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'IS_NEW_CONNECTION', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'LOB', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'SOCIAL_MEDIA_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'ENTERTAINMENT_MOVIE_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CX_STATE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'TIKTOK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'INSTAGRAM_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'NEWS_READERS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'WHATSAPP', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'GENIE_USER_YES_NO', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'IS_PD_CONNECTION', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'NETWORK_STAY', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'BANK_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DATA_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'ARPU', 'type': 'DOUBLE'}, {'property': 'CHURN_MONTHS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'TAXI_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DEVICE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'ENTERTAINMENT_MUSIC_LOVER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'TWITTER_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'EZCASH_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'YOUTUBE_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'USERS_OF_HOSPITAL_CHANNELING', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'CYBER_GAMERS', 'type': 'INTEGER'}, {'property': 'DEVICE_TYPE', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'property': 'VIDEO_CONFERENCING_USER', 'type': 'INTEGER'}], 'labels': 'hbb'}]\n        Relationship properties are the following:\n        [{'type': 'has_hbb_connection', 'properties': []}, {'type': 'owned_dtv_by', 'properties': []}, {'type': 'owned_mob_by', 'properties': []}, {'type': 'has_mob_connection', 'properties': []}, {'type': 'has_dtv_connection', 'properties': []}, {'type': 'owned_hbb_by', 'properties': []}]\n        The relationships are the following:\n        ['(:`hh`)-[:`has_hbb_connection`]->(:`hbb`)', '(:`dtv`)-[:`owned_dtv_by`]->(:`cus`)', '(:`mob`)-[:`owned_mob_by`]->(:`cus`)', '(:`hh`)-[:`has_mob_connection`]->(:`mob`)', '(:`hh`)-[:`has_dtv_connection`]->(:`dtv`)', '(:`hbb`)-[:`owned_hbb_by`]->(:`cus`)']\n    

Things needs to be clarified
AWS claims that graph databases perform better than tabular structures as
the graph size grows. Are there specific configurations, indexing strategies,
or optimizations for Neptune that we might be missing?
Considering the significant query time (more than 30 minutes) compared to
its earlier execution time of 7 minutes, what are the best practices for
optimizing Gremlin queries to prevent timeouts?
The extended execution time is leading to increased costs. What
recommendations would you suggest to balance performance and cost,
including data modeling or query execution adjustments?
